# How do I ssh into a server over HTTPs?

Tags: nginx, ssh, proxy, http

I have a server that has a reverse proxy (NGINX) set up to host all my other websites/services on a single server. I would like to create a way to SSH into that server over HTTP. The reason I need to do it this way is that my server is running behind a VPN with port forwarding so the outside internet only has access to my server through a single IP and a single port.

I'm a little confused if this is possible or what I should be doing. From what I've seen I heard that I should set up an HTTP proxy on that server. Do I use SQUID for this?

Looking for some guidance, please.

Comment: This is a fairly unusual requirement. You might be able to run ssh daemon on port 80, but then it won't accept http. Probably easier to reconfigure your VPN to accept port 22.

Comment: @Tim Welcome to the insanity that is IPv4 address exhaustion combined with companies still not providing IPv6.

Comment: I set up my new server on AWS with IPv6, which works well, though I got an ipv4 address as well. Shame it's not universal yet. I've been using IPv6 at home for so many years I lost count.

Comment: @Tim I am unable to open any other port. The VPN addresses a single port to me and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

The conventional method would be for an admin to establish his own VPN connection to the network where your server is to perform maintenance.

But there are tools that allow “protocol  multiplexing” to allow you to connect with both http(s) and ssh (and other protocols) to the same port where subsequently the ssh protocol will be forwarded to your ssh daemon and your web traffic to your web server / reverse proxy : see for example sslh https://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh/README.html

Answer (score 1):

Some SSH clients - notably PuTTY - support SSH tunnelling over HTTP "out of the box". In PuTTY, you just need to select "HTTP" as a proxy type in "Proxy" tab while setting up a connection (and of course fill in your proxy details).

For regular command-line ssh client, you can use tools like [Proxytunnel](https://proxytunnel.sourceforge.io/) or [HTTPTunnel](http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/). Google for "SSH over HTTP", there are many results available.

Another option you may want to consider is to install a web-based terminal application like [Shell In A Box](https://linoxide.com/tools/web-remote-your-server/) on your server. Then you are able to use a terminal session right in your browser (this does not use SSH, it just logs in to your server directly from the web).

Comment: So for this setup, do I need to install anything on the server end because it seems like this software is just on the client end.

Comment: You only need a proxy on the server end; if you already have a proxy, the rest is done on the client side.

Comment: Of course if you want a web-based access (Shell In A Box), you need to install that on server.

Comment: Thank you, do you have a link or know what I can use to setup a proxy? I'm just not familiar with that.

Comment: You said you have reverse proxy via Nginx installed - isnt't this enough? You need to try.